# Create a Dynamic data SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have two tables in my sql server database

1st table

```
SID--Role
1--A
2--B
3--C
4--D
5--E
```

2nd table

```
RoleName--SID
Admin--1
Admin--4
QA--2
```

Output For Rolename 'Admin' should be

```
SID--Role--Exists
1--A--true
2--B--false
3--C--false
4--D--true
5--E--false
```

Can you guys please help me with a select query to get the above output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you would require to do the `joins` (i.e. `left join`) and use `case` expression to check role (i.e. admin) exists or not.

```
select t.SID, t.Role,
       case when (t2.RoleName is not null and t2.RoleName = 'Admin') 
            then 'true' else 'false' end [Exists]
from table1 t
left join table2 t2 on t2.sid = t.sid
```

However, you could also use `ANSI` SQL standard `COALESCE()` function *if support*

```
select t.SID, t.Role,
       case when coalesce(t2.RoleName, '') = 'Admin' 
            then 'true' else 'false' end [Exists]
from table1 t
left join table2 t2 on t2.sid = t.sid
```

Comment: Thanks Sharma exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Make use of CASE and left Outer Join

```
SELECT A.SID, A.Role,CASE  RoleName WHEN 'Admin' THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' end AS 'Exists'
FROM  #TEMP_ROLE A LEFT OUTER JOIN #TEMP_ROLENAME ON a.SID = #TEMP_ROLENAME.SID
```

Comment: Thanks Aswani I will try this one as well

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query also

```
DECLARE  @Role TABLE ([SID] INT,[Role] VARCHAR(1))
INSERT INTO @Role
SELECT 1,'A' UNION ALL SELECT 2,'B' UNION ALL SELECT 3,'C' UNION ALL SELECT 4,'D' UNION ALL SELECT 5,'E'

DECLARE @RoleDetails TABLE (SID INT,RoleName VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @RoleDetails
SELECT 1,'ADMIN' UNION ALL SELECT 4, 'ADMIN' UNION ALL SELECT 2,'QA'

(SELECT B.[SID],A.[Role],'True' AS EXIST FROM @Role A 
INNER JOIN @RoleDetails B ON A.[SID] = B.[SID] AND B.RoleName = 'ADMIN')
UNION ALL
(SELECT A.[SID],A.[Role],'False' AS EXIST FROM @Role A 
LEFT JOIN @RoleDetails B ON A.[SID] = B.[SID] WHERE A.[SID] NOT IN 
(SELECT A.[SID] FROM @Role A INNER JOIN @RoleDetails B ON A.[SID] = B.[SID] AND B.RoleName = 'ADMIN'))
```

Thanks